# TailwindCSS truncate class never being used - tons of horizontal scroll instead

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am having come troubles with Tailwinds `truncate` class: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-overflow#truncate

It seems like a super smart utility but it seems like browsers will do anything to not truncate text - including a super long horizontal scroll that is in no way desirable.

How can i make browsers more lenient on just truncating the text?

[image: Picture of browsers not truncating the text]

Comment: `truncate` needs `width` to be specified. Max-width. You can do `truncate max-w-[99%]` and you will see the truncate working. It's not always required as it depends on the parent width as well

Answer (score 0):

You might need to share the html code for better understanding of the layout.

To properly `truncate` a text in Tailwind please make sure that the truncated element has a tag `<p>` and in some cases you might want to try setting the parent element to `block`, or use `w-full` and/or avoid `flex`

```
<div class="block">
    <p class="truncate">Well-Being: The Foundation of Thriving Business
    </p>
</div>
```

Again, not seeing the source layout it's hard to tell if this the best solution since horizontal scrolling can be avoided using many tools offered by Tailwind, such as grid layout, responsive layout based on the screen size, width manipulations, etc.